# How to stop Hibernate from logging in catalina.out/catalina.log

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

After tomcat starts up Hibernate starts logging in `catalina.out`.

((

Since I've removed console handler from tomcat/conf/logging.properties, it has started logging in `catalina.{date}.log`. Using below code:

```
#.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler
```

)).

This has started to happen after I have moved from `logback-classic.1.1.3` to `log4j.2.7`.

Below is log4j2.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, file

 #####  ####### #     #  #####  ####### #       #######
#     # #     # ##    # #     # #     # #       #
#       #     # # #   # #       #     # #       #
#       #     # #  #  #  #####  #     # #       #####
#       #     # #   # #       # #     # #       #
#     # #     # #    ## #     # #     # #       #
 #####  ####### #     #  #####  ####### ####### #######
#status=error
#name=PropertiesConfig

#filters=threshold

#filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
#filter.threshold.level=debug
#appenders=console
#appender.console.type=Console
#appender.console.name=STDOUT
#appender.console.layout.type=PatternLayout
#appender.console.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
#rootLogger.level=debug
#rootLogger.appenderRefs=stdout
#rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref=STDOUT



#######   ###   #       #######
#          #    #       #
#          #    #       #
#####      #    #       #####
#          #    #       #
#          #    #       #
#         ###   ####### #######
status=error
name=PropertiesConfig

property.filename=/var/log/app.log

filters=threshold

filter.threshold.type=ThresholdFilter
filter.threshold.level=ERROR

appenders=rolling

appender.rolling.type=RollingFile
appender.rolling.name=RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName=${filename}
#appender.rolling.filePattern=/var/log/app-log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log
appender.rolling.filePattern=/var/log/app-log-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type=Policies
#appender.rolling.policies.time.type= TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
#appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
#appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
appender.rolling.policies.size.type=SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.size.size=1MB
appender.rolling.strategy.type=DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.rolling.strategy.max=20

loggers=rolling,rollingORG,rollingCOM,rollingHIBERNATE

logger.rolling.name=com.nm
logger.rolling.level=ERROR
logger.rolling.additivity=false
logger.rolling.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile

logger.rollingHIBERNATE.name=org.hibernate
logger.rollingHIBERNATE.level=ERROR
logger.rollingHIBERNATE.additivity=false
logger.rollingHIBERNATE.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile

logger.rollingORG.name=org
logger.rollingORG.level=ERROR
logger.rollingORG.additivity=false
logger.rollingORG.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile

logger.rollingCOM.name=com
logger.rollingCOM.level=ERROR
logger.rollingCOM.additivity=false
logger.rollingCOM.appenderRef.rolling.ref=RollingFile
```

Below is tail of catalina.out

```
21-Feb-2017 18:01:28.769 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
21-Feb-2017 18:01:28.790 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8442"]
21-Feb-2017 18:01:28.791 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8011"]
21-Feb-2017 18:01:28.792 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 52869 ms
21-Feb-2017 18:05:29.870 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generatePositionalParameter [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 74.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:29.870 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generatePositionalParameter [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 91.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:29.871 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.generatePositionalParameter [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 106.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.050 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 62.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.055 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 77.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.055 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 91.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.056 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 109.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.056 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 121.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.059 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 144.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.066 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 163.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.118 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 58.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.122 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 84.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
21-Feb-2017 18:05:30.123 WARN [http-nio-8442-exec-10] <unknown>.<unknown> [DEPRECATION] Encountered positional parameter near line 1, column 90.  Positional parameter are considered deprecated; use named parameters or JPA-style positional parameters instead.
```

Kindly help me out.

Thanks.

```
Tomcat Version : 8.0.15
Hibernate-Core : 4.3.7.Final
Hibernate-Commons-Annotation : 4.0.5.Final
```

Log4j2 Dependencies

```
compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:2.7"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.7"
compile "org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.7"
```

Answer (score 1):

Set up a different Log Level for hibernate packages may work -

```
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
```

Or
try this , it worked for me
**`java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.OFF);`**

Comment: You can set the following values.: log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL= warning

Remove the following line if you have it: log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql = trace